# lightning:datatable row action being blocked

Tags: security, lightning-datatable

I have a 3 row actions for my datatable row. For some reason it is being block and console is saying it is a security error. I am not sure why error is occuring as I am just doing an alert.

Here is the error:

> Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-032ebcb5-7130-bed3-6895-02101222c908' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://sfdc.azureedge.net *.ap4.visual.force.com https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list

Here is my code:

DataTable:

`<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}" data="{!v.data}" keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="true" onRowAction="{!c.handleRowAction}" />`

v.columns:

`//Columns
var actions = [
    {label:'Edit',name:'edit'},
    {label:'Delete',name:'delete'},
    {label:'Close Task',name:'close_task'}
];
cmp.set('v.columns',[
    {label:'Subject', fieldName:'linkName', type:'url',
     typeAttributes:{label:{fieldName:'Subject'}},
     target:'_blank'
    },
    //{label:'Name',fieldName:'WhoId',type:'text'},
    //{label:'Task',fieldName:'IsTask',type:'boolean'},
    {label:'Due Date',fieldName:'ActivityDate',type:'date'},
    {label:'Status',fieldName:'Status',type:'picklist'},
    {type:'action',typeAttributes:{rowActions:actions}}
]);`

handleRowAction function:

`handleRowAction : function(cmp,evt,hlpr) {
    var action = evt.getParam('action');
    var row = evt.getParam('row');
    switch(action.name) {
        case 'edit':
            alert('edit');
            break;
        case 'delete' :
            console.log('delete '+row.Id);
            break;
        case 'close_task' :
            alert('close '+row.Id);
            break;
    }

}`

I am not seeing what could be the issue.

Comment: Do you get the error when page loads or after doing the action?

Comment: I am seeing the error after doing the action

Comment: And if you put breakpoint there, what exactly do you get? On which line of code do you get the error?

Comment: Thank you @ItaiShmida for looking into this. It seems that I should've use "onrowaction" instead of "onRowAction". That was firing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I should've type onrowaction instead of onRowAction as property o the lightning:datatable component. Answer is from my [question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000QuncQAC) in developer.salesforce.com